# What is a "true cryonics revival patient" in Lindsay Buroker's "Star Kingdom" series?

Tags: star-kingdom

From the prologue of *Hero Code* (book 3 in the series):

> Fire burned in Yas’s veins as the treatment solution flowed into his arm. His breath caught, and his entire body clenched in pain.
>
> Had he been a true cryonics revival patient, he would have still been dead, and he wouldn’t have had to live through this. He supposed feeling envious of a corpse was strange.

What is this “true cryonics revival patient" he's talking about? Was he not doing not true cryonics?

Why would he have still been dead (isn’t he a revival patient?)? Why would he be feeling envious of a corpse?

Comment: Hope my edits reflect what you meant).  If not, feel free to rollback the changes.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't read this series, but I'm familiar with the author.  I don't know how the characters ended up needing medical care, but here's what I can tell reading the prologue.

The treatment involves a solution that causes cells to regenerate.  Yas thinks about this when thinking about his companion's cybernetic components:

> I suppose they don’t have cells that need regenerating.

So, while it does this, it does apparently cause some pain/burning sensation.

I believe what is meant is that, if he had been truly dead, they would have done the cell generation first, then brought the person back once that process (and the associated pain) was over.  In that way, he is somewhat envious of someone who actually died since he wouldn't feel the pain if he had, but still happy to be alive.

---

[Cryonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryonics) refers to taking the body of a deceased person--someone who has officially died--and freezing it in the hopes of being able to later a) fix whatever caused the death and b) afterwards bring them back to life.

I'm inferring from the prologue that if he was frozen, Yas was put under [cryopreservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryopreservation) instead.  This is the freezing of **living** tissue to stop all chemical processes.  Someone in cryopreservation would not be a "true cryonic" since they never actually died.  A subtle difference, but apparently an important one for this process.

Comment: In the book it says they were doing crionics .But the character says “if he was a true cryonics revival patient”?